# Expiration date of US 5,618,582?

Tags: patent-lifetime, expiration, us5618582

I want to know the date of expiration of VanWinkel's Liquid Mask patent [US 5,618,582](http://www.google.com/patents/us5618582).

Answer (score 3):

The patent application was filed on June 7, 1995 and issued on April 8, 1997.

US patents issuing from patent applications **filed on or after June 8, 1995** have a term of 20 years from the earliest non-provisional patent application priority date.  US patents issuing from patent applications **filed prior to June 8, 1995** have a term equal to the greater of 17 years from issuance or 20 years from the earliest non-provisional patent application priority date.

In this case, since 17 years after issuance is greater, the patent expires on April 9, 2017.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but I have asked an [additional question](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/13217/14417) regarding the effect of the divisional, continuation, continuation-in-part and abandoned patents that this patent is based on. If those are taken into account, the filing date is July 25, 1990, giving an expiration date of April 8, 2014.